# Azure Web Role apply https binding to multiple instances

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, multiple-instances, sni, webrole

I have two web roles scaled up to 4 instances and at least two instances are running at a time. The certificate requested by a user via first website is pushed to blob storage and creates a queue message for the other website to read it.

I have a while loop inside the Run method implementing RoleEntryPoint to check the message, upload the certificate to store if available, apply https binding, and delete the message.

The bindings are applied to current instance and not into both. Is there a way to I can access all instances and apply bindings to both at once? If not, what are some better approaches?

Comment: Do you want to update two original instances at once? Or the scaled one and the original one at once?

Comment: Two original instances as of now.

Comment: I think that you cannot achieve this by Azure for now. Because they are two different instances. you need to update both of them.

Comment: Any idea to handle it better way? Whenever request is routed to other instance, the ssl warning is being displayed since binding is not added to that particular instance.